# I can't do hibernate to my PC due to swap partition size is equal zero?

Tags: partitioning, swap, hibernate

How can I do that swap partition without losing data 
when I used

```
~$ free -k
```

The output was:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3891772    3207580     684192     410972      58428    1086932
-/+ buffers/cache:    2062220    1829552
Swap:            0          0          0
```

[image]
[image]

What should I do for enabling hibernate?
when i used the command sm - hibernate the PC gave ma a dark screen and  opend

Comment: The second screenshot shows you have made a linux swap right.

Comment: ~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3891772    3689848     201924     436212      88308    1435292
-/+ buffers/cache:    2166248    1725524
Swap:            0          0          0

----

Comment: no answer til now

Answer (score 0):

Just download the G-parted "gparted.org". If you have already done that the just boot from it or burn the downloaded iso to a CD or USB, then boot from it.

Then, delete the previous linux-swap and make a new one.

If you have made the linux-swap partition, then boot into your Ubuntu launch Gparted.

1. Right-click on linux swap and click on "Information".
2. Copy the UUID.

   [image: UUID]
3. Type in the command:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
   ```
4. There where it is wriiten UUID for swap, replace the one with the one you copied.

   [image: Swap]
5. Save and exit.
6. Then, open terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo swapon --all && sudo swapon --all --verbose
   ```
7. Reboot.

Apart from this, you have to do the following:

8. Type in the following command:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
   ```
9. There you copy and paste the following, replacing anything that is there:

   ```
   [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
   Identity=unix-user:*
   Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
   ResultActive=yes

   [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
   Identity=unix-user:*
   Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
   ResultActive=yes
   ```
10. Save and exit.

Now, see if your hibernate works:

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

OR from the shut-down menu.

Hope it helps! Thank You!

Comment: how can i re-size that swapped one to the previous partition as the first image ?

Comment: Delete that linux swap. Make a new one. And remaining space, join it with the ntfs file system.